# Disabling API function via hotpatch (not globally)

Tags: winapi, dll

A third party library that I am using regularly tampers with several Windows API functions, the most annoying one being `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`. Which, unsurprisingly, makes my own handler entirely obsolete (try and find out why, if you don't know!).

I'd like to work around this stupidity. The obvious way would be to overwrite the the 5-byte hotpatch prologue with `xor eax,eax ret 4` (after having called the function myself), effectively making any further calls no-op.

There are two concerns with this:

1. Other programs that are running at the same time might want to legitimately call a patched function. They might *not* be totally braindamaged and might do something useful. Since shared libraries are *shared*, any other programs loading or already having loaded the same DLL while my program is running will be subject to the patch until my program restores the functionality at exit.
2. `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` lives in `kernel32.dll`, which is never unloaded. This means that in case of unanticipated non-exception program termination (i.e. user kills the process in TaskManager), the patch will persist until the machine is rebooted. This is a very nasty feature.

Is there a reliable way of doing such a thing and not disrupting/compromising proper functionality of the entire system at the same time?

I have thought about setting protection to `PAGE_WRITECOPY` rather than `PAGE_WRITE` before applying the patch (`PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY` is tempting too as it shouldn't require resetting protection to `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` afterwards, but MSDN says this is only supported after Vista SP1, and XP functionality needs to be maintained).

In my understanding, this should constrain visibility of any changes I make to my process.

Is this a valid assumption, and will such a thing work, also in accordance with other features that I've maybe not thought of (such as DEP, or some special privilegues or other interferences)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [replace that IAT entry](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/IAT_Hooking.html) in the 3rd party library that points to `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, this is far simpler, and is local to the 3rd party library *only*.

Even better, if the 3rd party library is a dll/binary that you distribute with your app, you can just `NOP` out the calls it makes to `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`, this would prove easier and safer.

> I have thought about setting protection to PAGE_WRITECOPY rather than
>   PAGE_WRITE before applying the patch (PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY is
>   tempting too as it shouldn't require resetting protection to
>   PAGE_EXECUTE_READ afterwards, but MSDN says this is only supported
>   after Vista SP1, and XP functionality needs to be maintained).

Actually, `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` is your best bet, but its generally a good idea to restore the original privileges, unless you need to check if you or someone else tampered with the memory already.